# Gridster hanging when the widgets are of large sizes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gridster

I am not quite sure if its a gridster issue but any help is greatly received. When I add multiple widgets of size 13x16 (imagine the widget size as large enough to cover an average PC screen) the browser just hangs (Browser Not Responding). Firebug doesnt show any issues.

Please find below my gridster configuration

```
$scope.gridsterOptions = {
        margins: [10, 10],
        columns: 50,
        width: 'auto',
        height: 'auto',
        resizable: {
            enabled: true,
            handles: ['n', 'e', 's', 'w', 'ne', 'se', 'sw', 'nw'],
            start: function(event, $element, widget) {
            },
            resize: function(event, $element, widget) {
            },
            stop: function(event, $element, widget) {
            }
         },
         draggable: {
            enabled: true,
            handle: '.widgetHeader',
            start: function(event, $element, widget) {
            },
            drag: function(event, $element, widget) {
            },
            stop: function(event, $element, widget) {
            }
         }
    };
```

FYI:
        If widget size is 6x6 then there are no issues. I tried upto 25 widgets with no noticeable performace issues. 
        However, if the widget size is 13x16, with just 3 widgets, I am getting browser not responding issue.

Can you kindly give me some pointers to resolve this?